# How can you rename variables in an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm needing a way to rename the variables in a large batch of Oracle stored procedures. The problem I'm seeing is that the stored procedure variable names are also Column names in the table, so an edit, replace would not work.

So for example, in the following procedure, how could I replace the variable named: COMPANYID to be called PARAM_COMPANYID?

The whole point of doing this is, we work for a place that does not provide the ability to call a stored procedure.  We do have the ability to run SQL script.  Currently, when we run a stored procedure, we have to manually edit replace all of the variables with the actual value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE          SP_TEST(
, COMPANYID IN integer default null
, OUTPUT OUT types.cursor_type  
) AS


BEGIN

OPEN OUTPUT FOR

SELECT   
  COMPANYID
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME,    

from
(
    select distinct 
    COMPANYID
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME
    FROM ALL_COMPANYS C
    WHERE C.COMPANYID=COMPANYID

) TEMP
where TEMP.COMPANYID = DECODE(COMPANY,0,COMPANYID,NVL(COMPANY,COMPANYID))  

GROUP BY 
  COMPANYID
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME;
```

The end result would look like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE          SP_TEST(
, PARAM_COMPANYID IN integer default null
, OUTPUT OUT types.cursor_type  
) AS


BEGIN

OPEN OUTPUT FOR

SELECT   
  COMPANYID
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME,    

from
(
    select distinct 
    COMPANYID
    FIRSTNAME,
    LASTNAME
    FROM ALL_COMPANYS C
    WHERE C.COMPANYID=PARAM_COMPANYID

) TEMP
where TEMP.COMPANYID = DECODE(COMPANY,0,COMPANYID,NVL(COMPANY,PARAM_COMPANYID))  

GROUP BY 
  COMPANYID
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME;
```

If there was a way to rename all of SQL parameters to the end result (above), then I could write an edit/replace process using C# to convert these stored procedures into runnable inline script.

Comment: *"the Stored Procedure variable names are also Column names in the table"* is very bad practice. Such clashes inevitably cause problems with the result set. Where do the original scripts come from? Anyway I can see why you would want to edit the stored procedures but I don't understand why the second version of the stored proc gets around the ban on *"the ability to call a stored procedure"*

Comment: Correct me when i'm wrong, but looking at the parameters of the DECODE function, even Oracle couldn't distinguish between COMPANYID as a column and as a parameter?!

Comment: @Yosh, in the decode Oracle would take the `companyid` from the query due to the scoping rules.  @Robbieone, you could change any `companyid` value that you want to reference the procedure variable of the same name to `sp_test.companyid` however there is no algorithm that's going to be able to decide for you which references will need to be changed.

Comment: @Sentinel Yeah, that's what i thought too, but in the "result"-version one of them is a parameter, so the initial version would never result in what the may have expected... Thanks.

Comment: I agree with APC. It's not good practice, but something I found I have to deal with.  The line with the DECODE statement was taken from one of our real production procs.  I too wondered how Oracle know which one is which.  Somehow Oracle is able to tell the difference and somehow Oracle is able to parse these procs using its own internal algorithm.  I was hoping that there was a way to get access to that, but it appears there is not.  Thank you APC, Yosh, Sentinel

Answer (score 2):

Code like this is bad practice:

```
WHERE C.COMPANYID=COMPANYID
```

Clearly the developer who wrote it considered it obvious that, un-aliased and un-prefixed, `COMPANYID` referred to the parameter of the same name. In fact, the compiler will apply the matching label which is nearest in scope, which is **the table column name**. So that WHERE clause is interpreted as

```
WHERE C.COMPANYID=C.COMPANYID
```

That is, `where 1=1`. Not good. So, renaming the parameters to something distinctive is crucial.

The bad news is, there is no magic way of doing this. You will have to edit each procedure's source by hand. Don't entertain the possibility of using regular expressions in a global search and replace operation. From the sample you have posted here the column references are not always aliased so there's no way to write a search and replace expression which could tell (for instance) that `COMPANYID` in `GROUP BY COMPANYID` is a column and not a parameter.

So unfortunately you have a long and tedious exercise of finding every occurrence of a parameter name, deciding whether it is in fact a parameter and modifying it when appropriate. Try not to spend too much time wishing inventive tortures upon the developers who wrote the original scripts. Entertaining though it might be, it is distracting and will lead to the introduction of new bugs or the missing of existing ones.

Here is a script which you can use to scope the task ahead (assuming you have a schema where these procedures are compiled).

```
select package_name
      , object_name as procedure_name
      , argument_name as parameter_name
      , case when length(argument_name) > 28 then '!' end as uh_oh
from user_arguments
where position > 0 -- eliminate function return values
and argument_name in ( select column_name from user_tab_columns )
order by package_name
         , object_name
         , position
```

The subquery  on `user_tab_columns` is optional. It allows you to address only the parameters which are troublesome right now. Omit it if you want to tackle all the parameters.

The `uh_oh` attribute will identify parameters which are too long to rename with a simple `P_` prefix. You suggested code proposes `PARAM_` as a prefix but that is unnecessarily long, and is likely to generate more name changes than a two character prefix.

Comment: Thank you @APC.  That's a great write up.  I'm still thinking that maybe someone has created a parser (out there somewhere) to do this.  If I can't find one, then I may try to create one myself.  To answer your question, the reason that this gets around the sp ban on calling a proc, is because I could create c# code that pulls the proc's text, and replaces all parameter instances with VALUES.  The entire script would run as a single statement, rather than being run as a proc.

Comment: If you are serious about using a PL/SQL parser for this task, have a look at Porcelli. [Find it here](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser). No warranty implied or offered.

Comment: that's more along the lines of what I'm looking for. Thank you.